# How to check if a string is an array before parsing?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, string, eval

I have a an arbitrary string that I would like to test if it is in array format before parsing. Here is what my string looks like:

```
var stringVar = "[{id:123,abc:123,xyz:987},{id:456,abc:789,xyz:1}]"
```

To parse this into an array, I am doing:

```
var arrayVar = eval(stringVar);
```

I am worried of malicious code, so I want to check if `stringVar` is an intended array before running `eval` on it. Any idea on how to approach this?

Comment: Consider converting that string into proper JSON syntax (with quotes around key names and string values) and then using `JSON.parse()` instead.

Comment: That string is coming from another system so I don't have control over changing it. How can I take that string and convert it to proper JSON without crazy string manipulations?

Comment: Well, in that case you can use this ugly regex: `if(yourString.match(/^\[({((id|abc|xyz)\:\d+)(,((id|abc|xyz)\:\d+)){0,}\})(,{((id|abc|xyz)\:\d+)(,((id|abc|xyz)\:\d+)){0,}\}){0,}\]$/)) { ... }`.. But it hard-assumes key names as given in your string.

Comment: Appreciate the thoughts, however, the parameters are arbitrary too so `abc` can be `foo` and other times maybe `bar`, etc.

Comment: Not getting this. Your `stringVar` is not a string, it's just an Array object. You don't need to eval it or parse it or anything else. Did you mean to say `stringVar = "[....]"`?